# How to build latest gRPC c++ into a dynamic library

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, grpc

I am trying to build grpc c++ using cmake into dynamic library with "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" but got errors like

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_BIO_callback_ctrl", referenced from:
ssl_callback_ctrl(bio_st*, int, long (*)(bio_st*, int, char const*, int, long, long)) in bio_ssl.cc.o

It feels like it has trouble finding the boring ssl library. How can I build grpc into dynamic library properly.
I've tried grpc version 1.49.3, 1.51.3 and 1.56.2.
Thanks.

Tried with -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON cmake flag but got error.